# Where are the bookmarks folders in Safari?

Tags: safari, bookmarks

While organizing my bookmarks, I made several folders.   Now when I click the Bookmarks menu, I don't see any sign of these folders.  I need to do "Show All Bookmarks" to see them.  Shouldn't the folder appear right in the Bookmarks menu?

Answer (score 1):

I think to clarify this, when you click the Bookmarks icon, you can create lots of new folders, with bookmarks.

However, the only ones that will appear in the bookmarks menu have to be in the collection - Bookmarks Menu.

If you create them lower down in the Bookmarks section, they will only be in that section. Yes, this is odd and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - folders work in the bookmarks menu. There are there are two places where you can store bookmarks, the bookmarks bar and bookmarks menu. Both support folders.